# How to force RIA Services to include a sub-entity in one Query method but not another

Tags: nhibernate, wcf-ria-services

Here's the scenario:

I've got an association between "Groups" and "Users, represented by a "UserGroupAssignment" object.

```
public class UserGroupAssignment
{
  [Key]
  public virtual long Id { get; set; }

  [Association("UserAssignmentToUser", "UserId", "Id", IsForeignKey = true)]
  public virtual User { get; set; }  

  [Association("UserAssignmentToGroup", "GroupId", "Id", IsForeignKey = true)]
  public virtual Group { get; set; }    

  public virtual bool IsPrimary { get; set; }    

  public virtual DateTime? ValidFrom { get; set; }    

  public virtual DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; }    
}
```

I have two business logic methods, GetUserAssignmentsForGroups and GetGroupAssignmentsForUsers that I return the assignments with the User and Group properties populated respectively. i.e. GetUserAssignmentsForGroup takes a GroupId and returns the assignments for that Group with the User property populated.

What I want is to expose those two methods as domain query methods like so:

```
[Query]
public IQueryable<UserGroupAssignment> GetAssignmentsForGroupWithUsers(long groupId)
{
  return this.businessLogic.GetUserAssignmentsForGroups(groupId);
}

[Query]
public IQueryable<UserGroupAssignment> GetAssignmentsForUserWithGroups(long userId)
{
  return this.businessLogic.GetGroupAssignmentsForUsers(userId)
}
```

My problem is that whilst the business logic methods return the correctly populated Assignments via NHibernate, RIA Services is NOT passing the sub-entities (User or Group) across the wire.

I don't want to use [Include] attributes on the User or Group properties of the UserAssignment class, as I want to minimise the payload over the wire - I don't want to send the group over when I'm only interested in the User of each UserAssignment, for example.

So my question is this:

> **How do I tell RIA services to
>   explicitly include User sub-entities
>   in one domain query method and Group
>   sub-entities in the other?**

Remember, I'm using NHibernate at the back end and custom query methods in the RIA Services, so can't use the EF-style include in the client query.

Thanks

Joel

Comment: Not sure how to answer your question, but you might consider adding the [nhibernate] tag to get folks from that area to help out too.

Answer (score 1):

you should apply the `[Include]` attribute in the metadata class. then create one domain service method for fetching data *without* properties included, and a separate method for fetching data with properties included.

You might find [this thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/95737/219510.aspx) helpful in understanding how `[Include]` attribute works.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still interesting. Did you find a solution ?

As far as I know of WCF RIA Architecture it isn't so easy. 
An easy and dirty way could be to override the Query method, force the enumeration of the IQueryable being returned (I guess you're using LINQ to nHibernate, in which case, good luck) then examine the HttpContext (you're using WCF RiaServices so you MUST have aspNetCompatibility turned on) and set to null the reference that you don't want to send over the wire (User or Group).
Anyway this way FORCE you to use the [IncludeAttribute]. However I don't see any reasonable route that avoid its use, and this way allow you to send the entity over the wire just when you need to.

IMO I belive that in order to totally avoid the use of [Include] you must rollout your own serializer serverside and deserializer clientside or change the UserGroupAssignment entity so that the user property become a string containing the serialized User (or Group) that you decide to valorize or not according your method.

Please let us knows if you already found a solution, the question is interesting.